# Как сделать, чтобы анимация игралась 1 раз через On click?

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui, разработка-игр

При нажатии на кнопку переход обратно к бегу никак не получается, вот пример моей попытки:

```
public void onClick()
{
    StateAttack = !StateAttack;
    AnimAttack.SetBool("attack", StateAttack);
    if(StateAttack == true)
    {
        StateAttack = false;
    }
    
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Странный код... Можете попонятней объяснить, что вы хотите, и, главное, что вы имеете?

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть анимации уже в аниматоре и при нажатии на кнопку, переход к нужной анимации идет, однако данная анимация должна сыграть один раз и далее мне нужно сделать переход обратно, что и не получается соответственно

Comment: Разберитесь, как работает граф анимаций и переходов в Animator для начала, а не тупо копируйте одну строчку из интернетов.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы анимация проигрывалась один раз - нажмите в ассетах на саму анимацию, перейдите во вкладку "Animation", снимите галочку "Loop Time"

[image: Loop Time]

Answer (score -2):

Добавил ивент в конце анимации на метод с переходом к другой анимации(AnimAttack.SetBool("attack", false) - тело того метода), все работает.

Comment: Этот ответ можно улучшить. Ответ должен содержать рабочий код и быть понятен не только вам, но и будущим посетителям, которые будут искать решение для похожей проблемы.